# Comma operator in C++11 (sequencing)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, sequencing

The standard mentions **f(a,(t=3,t+2),c);** which would be an assignment-expression followed by an expression for the 2nd operator according to my understanding.

But the grammar lists it juxtaposed:

***expression:***

***assignment-expression***

***expression, assignment-expression***

[Working Draft, Standard for Programming
Language C
++ Revision N4140 (November 2014)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

Is someone so nice as to explain to me please what it is that I'm missing here?

Comment: First, an *assignment-expression* cannot contain a comma (outside of brackets or quotes, that is). Therefore, the *assignment-expression* to the left of the operator cannot be extended to the right of ``t=3``. Second, and *assignment-expression* is one that *may* contain an assignment, it doesn't have to. So, each side of the operator is technically an *assignment-expression*. This is just the weird but very useful world of context-free grammars (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar). The names of these rules often don't match what you would expect from natural language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you see

> ```
>  expression:
>     assignment-expression
>     expression, assignment-expression
> ```

It mean that there are 2 possibilities for expression. One possibility that it is just **`assignment-expression`** that is defined somewhere earlier. Or it is recursively represented as **`expression, assignment-expression`**

So after extending it you receive that expression is comma separated list of one or more assignment-expression tokens.

In the sample you're mentioned second parameter is expression (t=3,t+2) which consists of 2 comma-separated assignment-expressions - and since it appears "In contexts where comma is given a special meaning" it has to "appear only in parentheses".

To find out why assignment-expression could take a form of t+2 you have to go back from its definitions and choose first choice always

```
assignment-expression
-> conditional-expression
--> logical-or-expression
---> logical-and-expression
----> inclusive-or-expression
-----> exclusive-or-expression
------> and-expression
-------> equality-expression
--------> relational-expression
---------> shift-expression
----------> additive-expression - this is what you see
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that since the definition of *expression* is

> *expression*:
>
> *assignment-expression*
>
> *expression* `,` *assignment-expression*

the second line means that any *assignment-expression* can be considered an *expression*, which is why `t=3, t+2` is a valid expression.

So why is the grammar this way?  First note that the grammar for expressions builds its way in steps from the most tightly bound category *primary-expression* to the least tightly bound category *expression*.  (And then the fact that "`(` *expression* `)`" is a *primary-expression* brings the expression grammar full circle and lets us cause any expression to be more tightly bound than everything that surrounds it by adding parentheses.)

For example, the well-known fact that binary `*` binds tighter than binary `+` follows from these grammar pieces:

> *multiplicative-expression*:
>
> *pm-expression*
>
> *multiplicative-expression* `*` *pm-expression*
>
> *multiplicative-expression* `/` *pm-expression*
>
> *multiplicative-expression* `%` *pm-expression*
>
> *additive-expression*:
>
> *multiplicative-expression*
>
> *additive-expression* `+` *multiplicative-expression*
>
> *additive-expression* `-` *multiplicative-expression*

In the expression `2 + 3 * 4`, the literals `2`, `3`, and `4` can be considered a *pm-expression*, or therefore also a *multiplicative-expression* or *additive-expression*.  So you might say `2 + 3` would qualify as an *additive-expression*, but it is *not* a *multiplicative-expression*, so the full `2 + 3 * 4` can't work that way.  Instead the grammar forces `3 * 4` to be considered a *multiplicative-expression*, so that `2 + 3 * 4` can be an *additive-expression*.  Therefore `3 * 4` is a subexpression of the binary `+`.

Or in the expression `2 * 3 + 4`, `3 + 4` might be considered an *additive-expression*, but then it is not a *pm-expression*, so that doesn't work.  Instead the parser must recognize that `2 * 3` is a *multiplicative-expression*, which is also an *additive-expression*, so `2 * 3 + 4` is a valid *additive-expression*, with `2 * 3` as a subexpression of the binary `+`.

The recursive nature of most grammar definitions matters when the same operator is used twice, or two operators with the same precedence are used.

Going back to the comma grammar, if we have the tokens "`a, b, c`", we might say `b, c` could be an *expression*, but it is not an *assignment-expression*, so `b, c` cannot be a subexpression of the whole.  Instead the grammar requires recognizing `a, b` as an *expression*, which is allowed as a left subexpression of another comma operator, so `a, b, c` is also an *expression* with `a, b` as the left operand.

This doesn't make any difference for the built-in comma, since its meaning is associative: "evaluate and discard `a`, then the result value comes from evaluating (evaluate and discard `b`, then the result value comes from evaluating `c`)" does the same as "evaluate and discard (evaluate and discard `a`, then the result value comes from evaluating `b`), then the result value comes from evaluating `c`".

But it does give us a clearly-defined behavior in case of an overloaded `operator,`.  Given:

```
struct X {};
X operator,(X, X);
X a, b, c;
X d = (a, b, c);
```

we know that the last line means

```
X d = operator,(operator,(a,b), c);
```

and not

```
X d = operator,(a, operator,(b,c));
```

(I'd consider it particularly evil to define a non-associative `operator,`, but it is allowed.)

Comment: You wrote: "the second line means that any _assignment-expression_ can be considered an _expression_, which is why `t=3, t+2` is a valid expression." To prove this, you have to show that `t+2` is an _assignment-expression_. Could you show how to do this?

Comment: In this context, `t` is an _identifier_, _unqualified-id_, _id-expression_, and _primary-expression_. `2` is a _literal_ and _primary-expression_. Each _primary-expression_ is a _postfix-expression_, _unary-expression_, _cast-expression_, _pm-expression_, and _multiplicative-expression_. `t` is also an _additive-expression_, and `t+2` is an _additive-expression_, _shift-expression_, ..., _conditional-expression_, and _assignment-expression_.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I'm concerned yours is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax notation (see §1.6 of N4140).

It is mainly used to evaluate precedence, but the name can be misleading.

For example in [expr.ass] (§5.18) you have the folowing definition:

```
assignment-expression:
   conditional-expression
   logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
   throw-expression

assignment-operator: one of
   = *= /= %= += -= >>= <<= &= ^= |=
```

So an `assignment-expression` can be a `conditional-expression` or a `throw-expression` even if neither performs any assignment.

This just states that `a = b`, `throw 10` or `cond ? c : d` are expressions with the same precedence order.

Comment: Those three expressions do not have the same precedence order. The grammar specifies that `throw` binds tighter than `=`, and `=` to the left of `?:` is looser than the `?:`, and `=` to the right of `?:` binds tighter than the `?:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 f(a,(t=3,t+2),c);
```

Here, first, stores `3` into `t` variable, then calls function `f()` with three arguments. It means second argument value become `5` and pass to the function.

Comment: Yes, that's what happens. But how does it match the grammar *expression, assignment-expression* where it looks like the assignment should be *after* the comma?